Metadata API wrapper returns null for all entries
Let's say we have
MetadataService.MetadataPort service = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
service.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
service.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();
service.CallOptions = new MetadataService.CallOptions_element();
service.timeout_x = 120000;

List<MetadataService.PermissionSet> permissionSets = (List<MetadataService.PermissionSet>)service.readMetadata('PermissionSet',
     new List<String>{'Merchandiser'})
    .getRecords();
system.debug(permissionSets[0]);
system.debug('fields:' + permissionSets[0].fieldPermissions);

I'm sure that Merchandiser has field permissions but this code returns null. Moreover when in comes to Metadata.fullName its value is null as well.
What am i doing wrong?
UPD: What's strange - i really can retrive the contents for custom permset. Moreover, i can't see any standard permset in Workbench but only custom. What did i miss?
UPD: really looks like we need to use force__Merchandiser as a name

any chance this is a case sensitivity issue on Merchandiser? Also must be the API name, not label.  Note the examples in Github don't set service.CallOptions

@cropredy i' definately sure that Merchandiser is a correct API name moreover it's standard permset
